# is there a way we can search a taxonomy by another taxonomy WORDPRESS

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

i have a post with two taxonomy category.

This is a search filtering case.

I have 2 combobox for filtering.

combobox1
--- Property Status Category (all locations in taxonomy=property_status) ---

```
<select name="status">
<option>Upcoming Projects</option>
<option>For Sale</option>
<option>On Going Projects</option>
<option>Previous Projects</option>
</select>
```

combobox2
--- Location Category (and I would like to list/query all the locations in the options of combobox2 where the selected category in 'combobox1' is use on the POSTS too.) ---

```
<select name="location">
<option>location1</option>
<option>location2</option>
</select>
```

MY TAXONOMY

---Location Category--
location1,
location2,
location3,
location4,
location5

---Property Status---
Upcoming Projects,
For Sale,
On Going Projects,
Previous Projects

Comment: Kindly explain your question properly. I would require the correct taxonomy structure and an example of a situation to answer this question.

Comment: @kakashihatake2 hi.. i just review and add some information of my question.. I hope you can help me. thanks

Comment: Ok. So you want to display the _'Locations'_ according to the option chosen in the _'Property Status'_ select box. A simple way of doing this would be using **AJAX/jQuery**. Tell me, are you trying to create a form inside the post? If yes, which plugin are you using to make the form? If no, where exactly would you like to output these select boxes?